Iterating 150k records with 5 columns in it via an object type in a foreach loop container in SSIS with a stored procedure is taking too much time
I have a use case where I need to go though all the rows in a table and apply some transformations (also updates) to each row.
Below is how I am doing it now:

Created an object type variable and fetched all the 150k rows of data from a table into it using full result set using "Execute SQL Task" (it has 4 columns)
Used a foreach loop container to iterate each row coming from step 1.
Inside the foreach loop container, again used "Execute SQL Task" where I am calling a stored procedure with the 4 columns of the row as parameters

NOTE: The stored procedure has some validation checks and one update statement as well which will run for all the 150k records.
The issue is that it's taking almost 3.5 hours to process all the 150k rows, and that might not be acceptable as I might have to run this process at least once every 2 hours.
I have also tried to use script task and inside the script task, iterate the object value using ADO.NET, but the time taken is almost same 3+ hours.
Also the table which has 150k rows doesn't have a primary key identity.
Kindly help on how I can improve the performance of this process.
Details: below is the Execute SQL Task which fetches 4 columns from a table with 150k records and stores it in a object type variable.
select aa, bb, cc, dd 
from xxxx; 

(say xxxx table has 150000 rows to process)

Then I am using this foreach loop container to iterate each row from the total 150 000 rows in table xxxx


Now I am using "Execute SQL Task" to call a stored procedure which contains logic; the stored procedure takes 4 parameters and processes them row by row, until the foreach loop gets exhausted.

The stored procedure looks something like this
CREATE PROCEDURE [Omg].[validateError]
    @DID varchar(50),
    @MGN varchar(100),
    @MN varchar(50),
    @SN varchar(20)
AS
    DECLARE @IsValidxx bit = 0,
            @IsValidyy bit = 0,
            @IsValidzz bit = 0,
            @IsValidww bit = 0,
            @HoldErrorCodes varchar(20) = 'Z',
            @InValidxxrErrorCode varchar(20) = 'D',
            @InValidyyErrorCode varchar(20) = 'A',
            @InValidzzErrorCode varchar(20) = 'M',
            @InValidwwErrorCode varchar(20) = 'G';
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @IsValidxx = CASE 
                             WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  aaaaaaaa WHERE DID = @DID AND TerritoryType = 'Level 1') 
                                 THEN 1 
                                 ELSE 0 
                         END;
        SET @IsValidyy = CASE 
                             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                          FROM bbbbbbb OFM 
                                          INNER JOIN ccccccc MG ON MG.Ordf = OFM.Ordf
                                          INNER JOIN ddddddddd M  ON M.Mod = MG.Mod
                                                 AND M.Available = 1 
                                                 AND MG.IsActive = 1
                                                 AND M.MN = @MN 
                                                 AND MG.MGN = @MGN) 
                                 THEN 1 
                                 ELSE 0 
                         END;

        IF @IsValidyy = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @IsValidzz = 1;
            SET @IsValidww = 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @IsValidzz = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  dddddd  WHERE MN = @MN AND SN=@SN AND Available=1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
                SET @IsValidww= CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  ccccc]  WHERE MGN = @MGN AND IsActive=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
        END

        IF @IsValidxx = 1 AND @IsValidyy = 1 AND 
           @IsValidzz = 1 AND @IsValidww = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @IsValidxx = 1;
            SET @IsValidyy = 1;
            SET @IsValidzz = 1;
            SET @IsValidww = 1;
        END
        ELSE 
            IF @IsValidxx = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @HoldErrorCodes = @HoldErrorCodes + @InValidxxrErrorCode;
            END

            IF @IsValidyy = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @HoldErrorCodes = @HoldErrorCodes + @InValidyyErrorCode;
            END

            IF @IsValidzz = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @HoldErrorCodes = @HoldErrorCodes + @InValidzzErrorCode;
            END

            IF @IsValidww = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @HoldErrorCodes = @HoldErrorCodes + @InValidwwErrorCode;
            END

            UPDATE [Import].[Recommendation] 
            SET ErrorCodes = @HoldErrorCodes 
            WHERE DID = @DID 
              AND MN = @MN 
              AND MGN = @MGN 
              AND SN = @SN;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
    END CATCH

And the whole process takes more than 3 hours to process 150k records


please provide more details, 2) is it possible to convert what you are doing into a set based operation?


how can i perform set based operation?

Please provide details as SQL to reproduce your scenario. While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Can't you write a new procedure which takes on all the rows at the same time with only one call? We can't help you if you don't write what is the magic voodoo you do with each row

@YitzhakKhabinsky - Updated the questions with more details

@siggemannen You mean to use cursor instead of ssis?  The stored proc is pretty simple which updates the table on the basis of few checks

Nope, i mean, you can update ALL rows are the same time once. Like a big join. If you post the code in text format, i'm pretty sure someone will be able to write it out for you

@siggemannen I can't update all rows at one time as each row needs to be validated against some conditions.. Still i will share the sql code snipped taking off sensitive data

Can validate many rows as well. Unless you have extremely complex validation which depends on previous rows, most things can be done, especially for such little amount as 150k rows

@siggemannen added the sql snipped. the table where we are doing the update inside the Stored Proc is the same table from where we are fetching the data in for each loop.

Seems over-complex, what's the point of IF @IsValidxx = 1 AND @IsValidyy = 1 AND  @IsValidzz = 1 AND @IsValidww = 1 BEGIN SET @IsValidxx = 1; SET @IsValidyy = 1; SET @IsValidzz = 1; SET @IsValidww = 1; END? If those values satisfy the IF you're setting them to the same thing again.

Yes, you should be able to rewrite this proc as a set-based operation. All of your conditions can be checked, and error codes concatenated, in a CTE that operates over your choice of input data: a #temp table, a table type variable, JSON or XML.

Aside... are you still using SQL Server 2012? Mainstream support for that ended in 2017, extended support in 2022. You should have finalized your upgrade path for that system several years ago already.

@AlwaysLearning Actually that IF condition when eveluates to true, should do nothing and therefore i couldn't find a way to just have blank as sql throws error when you leave it blank

@AlwaysLearning i am using sql 2014 and we are planning to upgrade it by this year end.

@AlwaysLearning - haven't ever used set based approach. Also every row is distinct in my case. Would you be able to help with a good example or may be a link which i can follow

IF @IsValidxx = 1 AND @IsValidyy = 1 AND             @IsValidzz = 1 AND @IsValidww = 1         BEGIN             SET @IsValidxx = 1;             SET @IsValidyy = 1;             SET @IsValidzz = 1;             SET @IsValidww = 1;         END this has no purpose? you should start by cleaning up the gunk

@siggemannen i Did clean out and now  what was taking 5 minutes to process around 5000 records is now taking around 4 minutes .. Still its a lot when processing 150k records.. I am now trying to find a way to update in sets seeing the data and understanding if it can be done

150K isn't a lot for SSIS. The normal way of using SSIS is to use a dataflow that reads data from a source, performs the conversions, validations, whatever you want to do over the stream of those records, and writes them to a target. Row-based validations can be done using the Derived Column transformation, adding an extra column for each validation expression. Lookup-based checks can use the Lookup transformation and setting a flag for unmatched rows. The lookup transformation can cache part or all of the lookup table, depending on how you configure it

The entire operation may take only as long as it takes to read the rows if the lookups use relatively small tables that can be cached in memory.

@PanagiotisKanavos - I have been doing things blindly in script tasks/components as i was not much comfortable with sql. I will look into your suggestions as well. Thanks

You should be able to do something like this:
update secondValidation
set ErrorCodes = concat(
            case when isvalidxx = 0 then @InValidxxrErrorCode end
            ,case when isvalidyy = 0 then @InValidyyrErrorCode end
            ,case when isvalidzz = 0 then @InValidzzrErrorCode end
            ,case when isvalidww = 0 then @InValidwwrErrorCode end
        )
--select *
from (
    select *
    ,   case 
            when IsValidYY = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  dddddd  WHERE MN = t.MN AND SN=t.SN AND Available=1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END AS IsValidzz
    ,   case 
            when IsValidYY = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  [ccccc]  WHERE MGN = t.MGN AND IsActive=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END AS IsValidww
    from (
        select *
        ,   IsValidxx = CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  aaaaaaaa WHERE DID = t.ID -- ??
                            AND TerritoryType = 'Level 1') 
                                         THEN 1 
                                         ELSE 0 
                                 END
        ,   IsValidyy = CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                  FROM bbbbbbb OFM 
                                                  INNER JOIN ccccccc MG ON MG.Ordf = OFM.Ordf
                                                  INNER JOIN ddddddddd M  ON M.Mod = MG.Mod
                                                         AND M.Available = 1 
                                                         AND MG.IsActive = 1
                                                         AND M.MN = t.MN  -- ??
                                                         AND MG.MGN = t.MGN)  -- ??
                                         THEN 1 
                                         ELSE 0 
                                 END
        from yourmaintable t
        ) firstValidation
    ) secondValidation
where IsValidxx + IsValidyy + IsValidzz + IsValidww <> 4

Just need to replace the variable joins with the joins against the main table, and you should be good to go.

This looks so compact and useful. I will give it a try on weekends and will let you know how it performs as i am away from my work space. Thanks again for your help

Any luck with this?
